# Kotlin extension functions with null checks

Tags: null, extension-methods, kotlin

Kotlin defines extension functions like `also` but they are not null checked. That's fine because you might not need the check. In case you do though, do you see any issue with the solution below?

```
inline fun <T> T?.ifNotNull(block: (T) -> Unit): T? {
    return this?.also {
        block(it)
    }
}

inline fun <T> T?.otherwise(block: () -> Unit) {
    this?: run {
        block()
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    "it".ifNotNull {
        println("You can use $it")
    }.otherwise {
        // will not happen
    }

    null.ifNotNull {
        // will not happen
    }.otherwise {
        println("You don't see it")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'll give my answer. One problem I had trying this approach is that there are too many combinations: there are cases when you want to use `also` cases when you want to use `let` etc. 
It looks like having the operators and the extension functions independently defined gives you the advantage of a kind of strategy pattern when you can combine different strategies to have an exponential number of configuration without having to define an exponential number of functions.

So you have

Operators:

```
 1. `?.`
 2. `?:`
```

Extension functions

```
a) `also`
b) `let`
c) `run`
d) etc
```

then you can combine operator `1.` with extension fun `b)` or operator `2.` with extension fun `c)` etc

If you try to define extension funs with null checks then you need to define one function for each combination: it's even difficult just to find names for the functions

So I will keep the `otherwise` helper fun but I will not use if `ifNotNull`

Answer (score 1):

I like @kingston's answer a lot, which is that basically that the functions you wrote are not necessary.

There is this stackoverflow question: [How to run code if object is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800036/)
.  The answer is to just use a plain `if-else` in such cases.  See furthermore this [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498562/in-kotlin-what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-deal-with-nullable-values-referencing-o#34498563) from another question.  It's just easier to read a plain `if-else` than other Kotlin solutions, such as this [solution using the elvis operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800036/how-to-run-code-if-object-is-null/#45800151).  Another advantage is that you can use an `if-else` either to just run a code `block` that does something and returns nothing like your functions do, or you can instead use `if-else` as an expression and return some value.

I also think your functions are not very "functional" because they carry their action strictly by side effects.  As mentioned above, the `block` does something and returns nothing.  In a more functional style, functions are chained and return transformed values at each stage.

The signature of `ifNotNull` is a bit odd since it runs a `block` that returns nothing and `ifNotNull` returns the raw object on which it is called instead.  I know this is so you can chain `ifNotNull` and `otherwise`, but the signature looks odd nonetheless.

---

Some extra code related to the comment below showing the compiler automatically knows a variable (`val` or `var`) within an `if (x != null) { }` block is not null:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var s: String? = "asfd"
    // println(s.length)  // Compile error.  Need s!!.length

    if (s == null) {
        println("null")
    } else {
        println("${s::class::simpleName}")
        println(s.length)  // compiles without or with s!!.length
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem with if-else is that if the variable is a var and not a val you either need to convert it into a val or you need to use the operator '!!' that's risky.

Comment: I don't know Kotlin much and I'm not sure what you are referring to.  I guest you are talking about the compiler automatically knowing that a var is not null within a `if (x != null) { }` block.  I tried with both `var` and `val` and it works fine in both cases without needing `!!`.  I edited my answer to add sample code.

Comment: @kingston I just realized you both asked the question and answered it.  See my reply above.